# Problema con Array, javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy empezando con javascript y tengo un problema que no se resolver:

Una funcion que recibe como argumento un array y un elemento devuelva la posicion que ocupa en el array.

> No se puede usar el metodo indexOf de Array y que si el elemento no existe en el array devolvemos -1.

```
var tortugas = ['Leonardo', 'Raphael','Michelangelo','Donatello'];
```

Inicio el array pero nose como seguir...

Comment: puedes agregar lo que intentastes hacer, en que te falla

Comment: Una solucion facil es que recorras el array con un bucle y compares el valor hasta encontrar la primera coincidencia. adicional debes tener una variable que te sirva de contador por cada iteracion, si terminas de recorrer todo el array y no hubo coincidencia retornas -1, si no retornas el valor de tu variable contador.

Comment: El método `indexOf` devuelve el index del elemento encontrado o -1: `['Leonardo', 'Raphael','Michelangelo','Donatello'].indexOf('Leonardo');` devuelve 0; `['Leonardo', 'Raphael','Michelangelo','Donatello'].indexOf('enxaneta');` devuelve -1

Answer (score 2):

Recorre el arreglo mediante un `for` así podrás saber en que indice se encuentra el elemento actual del `Array` : `arreglo[i]` siendo `i` el indice actual, realiza la comparación y retorna `i` si el elemento es igual al parámetro `elemento`, cuando acabe el bucle `for` se entiende que no hubo alguna comparación exitosa por lo tanto retornas un -1

```js
let arr = ['Leonardo', 'Raphael','Michelangelo','Donatello'];
let valor1 = 'Michelangelo';
let valor2 = 'Juan';

function encontrar(arreglo, elemento) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if(arreglo[i] == elemento) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(`${valor1} => ${encontrar(arr, valor1)}`);
console.log(`${valor2} => ${encontrar(arr, valor2)}`);
```

Comment: Listo @VickMuñoz

Comment: @DanielCrespo creo que esta respuesta era la que buscabas, si te a funcionado favor de marcarla como mejor respuesta. E visto tu perfil y llevas un par de preguntas con buenas repuesta y no has selecionado ninguna.

Comment: @Orlando De La Rosa te corrijo será en todo caso marcarla como la respuesta aceptada y no como la mejor

Comment: @Aprendiz cierto, gracias por la aclaración. ;-). tbn agregar que tampoco es obligatorio seleccionar una respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa nada es obligatorio. Pero aceptar una respuesta y darle votos positivos es una forma de agradecer y que la proxima persona que vea esta respuesta sepa que es de buena calidad y que realmente funciona. Si no, no es trabajar a ciegas. Es importante dejar eso en claro para los nuevos usuarios.